# @HeaderParam("Cookie") returns null when testing with curl -b "cookie:value"

Tags: java, spring, curl, jetty

I have function

```
@POST
@Consumes({ ExampleMediaTypes.PLAINTEXT_0_1_0, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, ExampleMediaTypes.SIMPLE_PROTOBUF_0_1_0, ExampleMediaTypes.SIMPLE_JSON_0_1_0, ExampleMediaTypes.STRUCTURED_JSON_0_1_0 })
@Produces({ PredictionMediaTypes.PLAINTEXT_0_1_0 })
@Path("/main")
public ChunkedOutput<String> doPredict(ExamplesIterable examplesIterable,@HeaderParam("User-Agent") String userAgent, @HeaderParam("Cookie") String cookies) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("hello");
    System.out.println(cookies);
    System.out.println(userAgent);
    return new RequestHandler(executorService, exampleProcessorFactory).handleRequest(examplesIterable);
}
```

That just prints cookie value, when I test it with :

```
curl -H "Content-Type:text/plain" -X POST -T /home/aleksander/bandit/daemon/test_cb.dat http://localhost:8080/vw-webservice-jersey/predict/main -v -b "cookieName:cookieValue;secondCookie:value"
```

I see :

```
hello
null
curl/7.35.0
```

What's the problem? Is this bad curl request or annotations mistake?